# Can any one help me out in sorting the array by inserting k new elements

Tags: sorting, data-structures

What is the time complexity (How to do) for inserting K new elements into the sorted array which contains N elements. This can be done in O(K Log K + N)

Comment: -1 "Can any one help me out" is the worst kind of title. This site is really becoming infested with bad quality questions.

Comment: I don't why -ve casting is there. Check for good answers.

Comment: Did you do a simple search for the answer before asking?  http://goo.gl/J17C8Q Possible duplicate of [Time complexity for Search and Insert operation in sorted and unsorted arrays that includes duplicate values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570325/time-complexity-for-search-and-insert-operation-in-sorted-and-unsorted-arrays-th)

Comment: @user Please re-read your last comment. That's not english. "I don't why -ve casting is there. Check for good answers." - I don't quite get what you're trying to say.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have a new answer like as follows

1. Sort the K new elements with merge sort which takes O(K * Log K)
2. Now merge the two sorted arrays (Use Third Array, after finishing remove first and second arrays). The first array is already sorted which contains N elements and the second array contains K elements which in turn takes O(N + K) which is going to be O(N).
3. So, the total time complexity is going to be O(K * Log K) (First Step) + O(N) (Second Step)
4. Total time complexity is O( K * Log K + N)

Comment: Would be nice to credit sashoalm for the actual answer.

Comment: @Gaminic It would. He commented the solution in my crap answer that I've since deleted

Comment: @schmop Please don't credit me. I don't think OP's question should be answered at all, it should be downvoted and closed instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data structure used. You mentioned "in an array", which makes it <strike>O(k * n)</strike> O(k + n). With other implementations it can be reduced to O(k log n), which is the (optimal?) complexity of finding the insertion position for each of the k elements.

However, an array doesn't allow for inserting. Inserting a new element on position i requires pushing all elements starting from the old i one space back. If i is close to the end that's okay, but near the start you'll end up moving nearly every element back, thus a worst case of O(n) per insertion. On top of that, an array has limited space. If your array wasn't made to fit n+k elements, you'll have to allocate new memory and copy from the old to the new.

[edit]

As mentioned by sashoalm, if all k new elements are known at the start, you can do better by first sorting the array of new elements (O(k log k)) and then merging them with the old array (O(n + k)). Provided k << n, this boils down to O(n + k) rather than O(k * n).